# UseJwtBearerAuthentication returns 401

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, firebase-authentication, .net-core

I'm using Firebase and dotnet core in my application stack.

I'm generating a JWT fine using the Firebase iOS API and can confirm that the structure is as expected and valid using [jwt.io](http://jwt.io/)'s parser.

#### The Setup

I've followed [this article](https://blog.markvincze.com/secure-an-asp-net-core-api-with-firebase/) to setup dotnet core to automatically set principal based on the request.

The configure method of my Startup file looks like this, where in practice the `<project-id>` part is replaced by the project app (which I can confirm is the same as the `aud` property in my parsed JWT as seen on jwt.io):

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();
    loggerFactory.AddSerilog();

    app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
    {
        AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
        IncludeErrorDetails = true,
        Authority = "https://securetoken.google.com/<project-id>",
        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {  
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = "https://securetoken.google.com/<project-id>",
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = "<project-id>",
            ValidateLifetime = true,
        },
    });

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

#### The Request

I have a controller action that I can hit at the url `http://localhost:5000/api/dashboard` and get the expected response when I don't have the `Authorize` attribute on the controller. I have then added the `Authorize` attribute back so I can start testing the JWT middleware.

I'm creating a request in Postman as seen in this picture:
[image]

#### The Response

As you can see in the picture above the response is a `401 Unauthorized`.

The server logs in my debug output look like this.

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/api/dashboard  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/api/dashboard  
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
      Authorization failed for user: (null).
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService:Information: Authorization failed for user: (null).
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult[1]
      Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult:Information: Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerMiddleware[12]
      AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was challenged.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerMiddleware:Information: AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was challenged.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action Sured.Api.Controllers.DashboardController.Get (Sured.Api) in 20.2369ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action Sured.Api.Controllers.DashboardController.Get (Sured.Api) in 20.2369ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 37.6488ms 401
```

### The Question

I've been researching on Google and trawling through source code and I simply can't crack this.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

For good measure, here's all the dependency versions in my project:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.5.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.Environment" Version="2.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.4.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="2.4.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.ElasticSearch" Version="5.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile" Version="3.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="1.1.2" />
```

Comment: Are there valid claims within the token to allow a valid principle to be generated? stack trace can't seem to identify a user.

Comment: That could sometimes be due to not being able to verify the token signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... turns out the likely reason it wasn't working is that the token I had been playing around with expired. I generated another one today and tried the postman query again and it worked.

So if you're having the same trouble, don't make my silly mistake, and make sure you've got a token that hasn't expired!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the key is already being added in by default. Possibly you may need to add the key into the post.
Key: `Authorization` Value: `Bearer eyjhbGciOij...`
This is necessary to have in a google API Post to allow for a secure Connection. The Dashboard automatically adds this key in.

Source:
Previous experience with The Google API